# Camel PollEnrich not working properly

Tags: apache-camel

After transforming a file with xslt I have to append a file downloaded from ftp. So I did the following:

```
    from("direct:adobe_productList_incremental")
            .id("routeADOBESPtransformPI_productList")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "---------Starting file: ${body}")
            .convertBodyTo(InputStream.class)
            .to("xslt:classpath:" + xsltTransformationProductList)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "---------Transformed file: ${body}")
          .pollEnrich(ftpType+"://"+ftpUsername+"@"+ ftpUrl +":" + ftpPort + ftpPath_incrementalComplete +"?password="+ftpPassword+"&fileName="+ftpFilename_incrementalComplete+"&passiveMode=true&binary=true&delete=false",10000)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "---------After poll enrich: ${body}")
            .to("file:{{file.root}}{{file.outbox.products_list_incremental}}?fileName={{file.outbox.products_list_incremental.name}}.final");
```

untill the poll everythin works (the transformation is done correctly), but after the pollEnrich the current body is overrided by the ftp content (and not appended as it should be).

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it works as designed.

By default the content will be overridden. If you need to append/merge or whatever, you need to use a custom aggregation strategy, and implement code logic that does this.

See the Camel docs at: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html about the ExampleAggregationStrategy.

The Camel docs says

> The aggregation strategy is optional. If you do not provide it
>   Camel will by default just use the body obtained from the resource.

Comment: Thank Claus, I used the ExampleAggregationStrategy but in the resource.getOut().getBody(); I get a null value i tried to do the following resource.getIn().getBody(); but also in this case I get null. So I'm unable to retrive the body from the ftp...
my poll enrich is now .pollEnrich(ftpType+"://"+ftpUsername+"@"+ ftpUrl +":" + ftpPort + ftpPath_incrementalComplete +"?password="+ftpPassword+"&fileName="+ftpFilename_incrementalComplete+"&passiveMode=true&binary=true&delete=true",10000, new AggregationStrategy() {....

Comment: Use getIn - see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: And if the body is null, then maybe there is no file as you wait for 10 seconds with the timeout.